# Filtering documents on SharePoint Online Library folder in a different site

Tags: caml-query, filter, highlighted-content-web-part

I have a mammoth document library with folders on a site. I'm trying to show specific files in these folders so this is how the original Library View displays:

[image: Library View]

I've migrated this over from a SharePoint 2013 site but the views haven't come across. I'm using a Highlighted content web part to point at the library and folder I've migrated across. I need to filter it so that it shows all the desired documents. Is it best to write a Custom query? Haven't really used CAML before so I'd appreciate any help on writing a query, or if there's a better approach I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Below is how I'm using the Highlighted content web part. Should the (((SIteID ...point at the right site, I shouldn't need to add it to the Query?

This is how I've written the query:

```
<Query><Where><eq>
<BeginsWith><OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name="BTG%20Documents"/>

<Value Type="FINANCE">/sites/XXXeHome/BTG%20Documents/Finance     </Value>

</BeginsWith></Orderby>
</eq></Where>
</Query>
```

I was hoping that this would show the files in the folder in the library and I'd be able to filter by then, but it's not showing anything?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QD1E.png`enter code here`

Comment: In your title, you say "folder in a different site" -- are you saying that the folder lives on one site (for example, "yourtenant.sharepoint.site/sites/SiteA", but you want to display them in a view on a different site (for example, "yourtenant.sharepoint.site/sites/SiteB")?

Comment: @willman exactly